# redis client pipeline does not work in twemproxy environment

Tags: redis, redis-py, twemproxy

I use [redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py) to operate on redis, and our environment use twemproxy as redis proxy. But looks clinet pipeline doesn't work when connect to twemproxy.

```py
import redis

client = redis.StrictRedis(host=host, port=port, db=0)
pipe = client.pipeline()
pipe.smembers('key')
print pipe.execute()
```

it throws exception when do execute method

```py
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Socket closed on remote end
```

In twemproxy environment, client pipeline doesn't work or it is an issue of redis-py ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Becouse of `twemproxy` supports not all redis commands.

Here is actual supported commands list https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy/blob/master/src/proto/nc_redis.c

Comment: In this case redis-py just send commands one by one. It`s not a redis MULTI command.

Answer (score 1):

redis-py pipeline will use transaction by default, try this:

```
pipe = r.pipeline(transaction=False)
```